# How to explicitly complete a promise in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, completable-future

**Flame alert**

It's so simple: I am super familiar with Java completable futures:

```
CompleteableFuture f = CompleteableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "Hello").thenApply(s -> s.concat(" world"))
```

This code may be followed by:

```
CompleteableFuture word1 = f.thenApply(s -> s + " I am a completable future"); // "Hello world I am a completable future"
CompleteableFuture word2 = f.thenApply(s -> s + " I am teapot"); // "Hello world I am a teapot"
// option 1 (non blocking):
word1.thenAccept(System.out::println);
// option 2 (Blocking)
System.out.println(word1.get());
```

Now in node.js:

```
const f = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    return resolve('Hello')
}).then(s => " world")
const word1 = f.then(s => s + ' I am a promise') // 'Hello world I am a promise'
const word2 = f.then(s => s + ' I am a teapot') // 'Hello world I am a teapot'

// option 1 (non blocking)
word1.then(console.log)
// option 2 (Blocking)
console.log(word1.???????)
```

Where is this 'option 2' for node js? Without this, I am forced to create a closure to update a simple value instead of having a return.

I would rather someone say 'you don't know what you're saying' and show me then allow my ignorance to persist.

Comment: node.js does not have a way to make a non-blocking async operation suddently become blocking and synchronous.  It does not do that.  It is an event-driven environment where nearly all I/O is non-blocking and async.  To use the node.js environment that's how you program with it.  And, by specification `p.then()` is always async.  The `.then()` handler will always get called on some future tick of the event loop, even if `p` is already resolved.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Promise.resolve()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve), which immediately returns a fulfilled promise.

```
Promise.resolve( "Hello" )
    .then( s => console.log(s + " world") ); // Outputs "Hello world"
```

If you want to immediately reject a promise, there is also [`Promise.reject()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject).

```
Promise.reject( "Hello" )
    .then( s => console.log( s + " world" ) )
    .catch( s => console.log( s + " mars" ) ); // Outputs "Hello mars"
```

However, as far as I know, it is not possible to get the result from a Promise in a synchronous/blocking manner as you've described. The closest feature is async/await, which [isn't widely supported](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-async_functions) just yet, and is not synchronous. It just allows for similar syntax to a synchronous call. It would allow you to write a function like this:

```
async function returnString () {
  let s = await Promise.resolve( "Hello" ).then( s => s + " world" );
  console.log( s ); // Outputs "Hello world"
}

returnString();
```

There is [a library](https://github.com/yortus/asyncawait) which allows you what is essentially an async/await polyfill.

async/await is [supported natively](http://node.green/#async-functions) in Node.js 7.3+ with the [`--harmony` flag](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/), which enables staged features that aren't considered stable just yet, and 8.0+ without a flag, and outside of that, it can be transpiled with [Babel](http://babeljs.io/) into something that's usable in more environments.

Comment: FYI.  async/await is just telling the interpreter to auto-wrap the code that follows in a `.then()` handler for you.  It's a syntax convenience.  Everything that was async and non-blocking before is still async and non-blocking when using async/await.  And, if you want to use async/await now, you can transpile your code using BabelJS.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the clarification @jfriend00 I'll make sure that's clear in my answer.

Comment: How can I do this `async` `await` without using a babel transpile? Using a promise is great, but at some point you have to know it's done.

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno I've looked, and there really isn't a way to do it in a synchronous manner as you described. Even `async/await` are just syntactic sugar as jfriend00 pointed out. It's really a consequence of how Node.js is implemented, to be non-blocking. If you have a bunch of stuff that needs to happen before you finish up, you can make it a bit easier to manage by feeding an array of promises to [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), but other than that, you pretty much need to take advantage of callbacks/resolves.

Comment: There's just no way I can think of to do it without creating a closure in the end.